# I need to connect two batteries together for tablet

Tags: batteries

I bought an Alldocube X tablet about 18 months ago and recently the battery swelled up and needs to be replaced.  I contacted the seller Banggood and Alldocube but it is out of warranty and they won't help.

I took the tablet apart and began searching for the battery but couldn't find one, further examination showed that the tablet had two batteries stuck together, doing a search for one of these was more successful.  I'm going to go ahead and order two of these batteries but my problem is wiring them together.

On the current dual battery set up, there is a long green strip of a circuit board (5mm X 142mm) that runs along the top of the two batteries and has 4 points that plug into or slot into both batteries (Positive+ and Negative- on each).  Batteries sold on the internet have a similar edge however they have two wires coming out.

My question is how can attach this circuit board/strip to two batteries,  do batteries have two labels poking out that I can attach to the strip?

Comment: A battery that dies in 18 months?? Sounds like complete junk. You are going to end up with buying a new tablet, so why not save time and money you are going to waste trying to fix it and do it now?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Probably data has no backup…

Comment: The battery is not dead, it has just expanded and separated the tablet, it still works.  I'm going to try and fix it and prevent needless e-waste.  Two batteries & shipping would cost €22 in total.  The tablet is for media consumption only, I make 3 backups of everything important and have nothing on the tablet.  Of course, the advice is to never to buy a cheap tablet, the cheap processor is inefficient and created a death loop with the battery.  I'm just trying to figure out how I will attach the battery to the circuit stip thing.

Comment: This question would be greatly enhanced by photos of the batteries and connections.